# Comparing coefficient of a fraction (in ln) with coefficient of metric variable (in ln)

Tags: regression, stata, poisson-regression, logarithm

I ran a Poisson regression with capital stock as main variable of interest.
The stock K is in natural logarithm (ln) and I want to decompose it in two parts in the following way because I am interested in the effect of K1:
ln(K) = ln(K1 + K2) = lnK1 + Ln((K1+K2)/K1))

I inserted both parts in my regression.

However, I am not sure how to interpret the coefficient of the 2nd part (it is a ratio between the total stock and stock1) and especially how to compare the coefficient with the coefficient of lnK1.
For example, can we say anything about whether K1 is more important for the outcome than K2 based on a comparison of the coefficients?